# Pyhtho Django. the messaa is from python file and i want to show it in HTML his code is working but I want the message will show as pop up or alert

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Pyhtho Django. the messaa is from python file and i want to show it in HTML his code is working but I want the message will show as pop up or alert

Register

```
{% if messages %}
{% for result in messages %}
<b style="color: green;">{{result}}</b>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting javascript?

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for result in messages %}
    <script>alert({{result}})</script>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```